# C# Converting HTML to MHT file

Tags: c#, html, com-interop, mhtml

I'm trying to convert an HTML file to MHT file using a code which uses interop ADODB and CDO files. The code itself which I'm using is not relevant. The problem is that the ADODB and CDO dlls are causing me problems since I've got some windows 7 stations and some windows XP stations and the dll versions are the problem.
Do you might know how can I convert HTML to MHT without using these interop files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did use them. The dll definitions in the project's file was different in the XP and Windows 7 stations so I copied the XP definitions of the dll from the xp to the win 7 and it worked.